# Building a triangle wave generator using two LM358 with single supply operation

Tags: oscillator, wave

I am trying to build a triangle wave generator with the following specifications:

- The triangular wave must oscillate between V_max=7.2 V ,V_min=1.6 V
- Duty cycle = 0.5 ±1%
- Frequency, f_osc= 8.5 kHz ±5%
- Supply voltage = 12V (single supply operation)

Does anybody have a formula or guide to build a triangle wave generator with two LM358 op amps?

The circuit I came up with does not give me the desired output:

[image]

Comment: There is literally a circuit shown in the LM324 datasheet. The LM324 is the quad version of the (dual) LM358. The formula for the oscillation frequency of your circuit is f=0 Hz.

Comment: Sounds like homework.  Think about this: the desired output waveform is not centered about GND, but your comparator transition levels are (because the inverting input is tied to GND).  Disconnect R3 and solve the comparator circuit first.

Comment: And - GND symbols point downward.  Always.

Comment: @AnalogKid Hi, can you explain further on that?

Comment: You'll get a lot closer if you do two things:  flip - and + on left opamp, and connect + inputs of both opamps to vcc/2.

Comment: @td127 what do you mean by connect + inputs of both opamps to vcc/2.?

Comment: td127 - don't think so.  Vcc/2 is not the correct operating point for any part of the circuit.  Also, how does making the left circuit an inverting amplifier set the output positive and negative peak values?  MODS - is there a way to downvote a comment?

Comment: All right, all right - the first stage is a square wave oscillator (so leave the + and - as is, sorry) and the second stage integrator shapes it into a triangle. You do need to connect the - input of the 1st opamp and + input of the 2nd opamp to Vcc/2. This can be done with simple resistor divider from Vcc.

Comment: The first stage is supposed to be an inverting comparator with hysteresis, not an oscillator.  My point (admittedly badly put) is that simply swapping the device pins changes the circuit to something completely different, rather than correcting the mistakes in the circuit.  Again, homework - no detailed answers.

Comment: Just trying to be concise. Yes, more pedantically, the the first stage _in conjunction with the 2nd opamp_ constitutes a square wave oscillator. The pin swapping idea (admittedly badly put) was my mistake. The problem that remains is the biasing of the opamp inputs.